# How to show Record Type in section Header?

Tags: visualforce, record-type

I have 10 record types. I want to display selected record type name as section header in VF page? how can i show that?

Comment: You can bind this information from your controller.  What kind of controller do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you use the standard controller (with ou without extension, it does not matter) of the Account object, you can do :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!Account.RecordType.Name}" subtitle="{!Account.Name}" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(Account.RecordTypeId))}" />
</apex:page>
```

If you use a custom controller :

```
public class myTest {
    public Account a { get; set; }

    public myTest() {
        Id theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        a = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name FROM Account WHERE Id =: theId];
    }
}

<apex:page controller="myTest" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!a.RecordType.Name}" subtitle="{!a.Name}" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(a.RecordTypeId))}" />
</apex:page>
```

I know the code is completely dirty but you get the idea ;)

The `rendered` tag is useful if the Account does not have a record type (it can happen when you create record types when accounts already exist for instance), so you avoid yourself a "Attempt to dereference a null object" error thrown at you face haha